# using sqlite3 in for loop in shell script gives error

Tags: shell, sqlite, scripting

Need to query a certain value from each file in a directory and put it in a file. I use the code:

```
#!/bin/bash 

ls -lrt | grep -w  "458752" | awk '{print $9}' | sort -V > list

for linename in cat list 
do 

/d/home/alima0152/Desktop/sqlite3 $linename "select trace_count from volume"; >> trc_count 

done 

rm list
```

But I get this error:

> file is encrypted or is not a database

Comment: I am also using the latest version of sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is trying to open the files `cat` and `list`.

To execute something and insert its output, use `` `...` `` or `$(...)`:

```
for linename in $(cat list)
```